# Can I configure IIS (7.5) FTP Server to have "unix-like" responses?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, ftp

I have a "quick" question.

I am setting up a FTP Server, using IIS, and, have a requirement, for this Server, by a user, that "Responses of the FTP server should be “unix-like”."

Question: Does IIS FTP allow for this, either by a setting, somewhere, or, possibly even, by default?

Hope, there is an "easy" answer to this!

Thanks!

:)

Comment: And what does the user mean by that?

Comment: well, I am not quite clear myself, but, I thought, maybe it was gonna be clear to some users here ;) if not, I guess, I can ask the user what exactly they mean by that. I thought this may refer to a "standard" way, in which unix-servers respond. I will ask!

Comment: You can set the directory output style of your FTP site. The directory output style can be either Microsoft MS-DOS operating system-based or UNIX-based, and the output style defines the format that is used when an FTP client sends a list command. 

I suspect that this is what they are referring to when they say they want it to be "unix-like"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can [change the directory output style to be UNIX-based](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0d2a9b2e-b697-4bb3-8a61-0fad73a1fa08.mspx?mfr=true).